# Browser loads duplicate copies of scripts

Tags: javascript, ruby, load, nginx

If I open my webpage and then look at developer tools on the browsers like chrome/firefox/ie, I see multiple copies of the same view/javascript files loaded. This can potentially screw up how javascript behaves wrt to its state.

Almost everytime, doing page refresh would solve it.

This happens very randomly.

I am not at liberty to post my code, but the set up is nginx/thin/ruby/haml.

What can lead to such behavior? is the problem on the server side or browser side?

Our initial hunch was that may be they are multiple versions of the same doc, but all of them are exact replicas. So I ruled out caching as possible culprit.

More info about the page:

1. No dynamic loading of scripts - simple script tags
2. No frames on the page - simple body tag with a form in it
3. No advertisement scripts on the page
4. happens on all browsers
5. intermittent - frequency is like once in 500 page loads

Comment: Are you using something like RequireJS to load scripts dynamically? Or do you show some advertisements that might load scripts?

Comment: no dynamic loading just simple script tags. no advertisements

Comment: Well then perhaps you can find the actual script tags in the DOM with the debugger and figure out what's going on; it's almost certainly something going wrong with your code or frameworks, server- or client-side.

Comment: @pointy - everytime i saw this happen i saw multiple copies of the view as well in the dev tools. may be duplicate view is the one thats triggerring duplicate scripts

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're just seeing the requests/responses for negotiating whether to download the file or to keep the cached version, and it's not actually downloading *and parsing* the file multiple times.  If it's only apparent from the network pane.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple frames/iframes in your page, you might mean that. (But I don't see how a refresh would 'solve it', I can only see a refresh changing the network view).

Comment: @lee - nope. they are multiple copies. because I am hitting break points on a copy once and a different copy another time.

Comment: @lee - no frames in the application, plain html doc with one form it it.

Comment: If you don't want to show us an example, you're going to have to replicate it somehow and show us that.  And I don't quite understand your break points / copy statement, what did you do and what do you see, exactly?

Comment: So if you use liveHttpHeaders in FireFox, do you see multiple requests for your files?

Comment: @lee - I already tried to do that, but I could never get that happening on a simple page outside my real application, let alone in a public page like jsfiddle. frequency on the real app is like once is may be 500 page loads.

Comment: @lee - regarding break points - lets say i have 2 buttons button1, button2 with click handlers handler1, handler2(both in same script file), i would hit handler1 for button1 and handler2 for button2. All I was saying there is it proves that there are indeed multiple copies of the files.

Comment: It's an intermittent problem?  I would try a concurrency test, you might have a threading issue, I don't know enough about the server-side technologies to advise further, if you see it in all browsers, it's probably going to be a server issue, *especially* if it's intermittent.

Comment: So, does it actually affect the functionality of your page when it happens?  The debugging tools might just be representing the page's state incorrectly, but I don't see that being true for all browsers.

Comment: @lee - yes, it does. sample would be an asynchronous operation would be initiated by copy1 but its response would be interpreted by copy2, thereby putting the requester block as well the receiver block in an inconsistent state.